# Deducing self-adjointness from given $2\times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can the following matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ be  a matrix of self-adjoint operator in inner product space in some (not necessarily orthonormal) basis?

**My approach:**  It is easy to check that eigenvalues of this operator are $2,-1$.
 And we can easily find eigenspaces in each case, namely $V_{-1}=\langle (-1,1)\rangle$ and $V_{2}=\langle (1,2)\rangle $.   Moreover, we know the following fact

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional euclidean space and $f:V\to V$ is an
>   operator. An operator $f$ is self-adjoint if and only if there is an
>   orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.

Let's define in our space $V$ the following inner product: $$\langle x,y\rangle=(x_1,x_2)\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
y_1  \\
y_2 
\end{pmatrix}, $$ where $x=(x_1,x_2), y=(y_1,y_2)$.

Let's denote $e_1=(-1,1)$ and $e_2=(1,2)$ then $e_1\perp e_2$ and $|e_1|=\sqrt{3}, |e_2|=\sqrt{6}$. Let's define new vectors $e'_1:=\dfrac{e_1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $e'_2:=\dfrac{e_2}{\sqrt{6}}$. So we see that $\{e'_1,e'_2\}$ is orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. So it means that initial matrix can be matrix of self-adjoint operator.

Is my reasoning correct?

Would be very grateful for any comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is correct.

In general, we can apply this reasoning to find that any diagonalizable matrix with real eigenvalues is self-adjoint relative to some inner product.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply! Could you also take a look at this topic, please? They are quite similar. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3593079/construction-of-inner-product-from-given-3-times-3-matrix