# Construction of inner product from given $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Can the following matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 & -5\\
0 & 2 & 3\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$ be  a matrix of self-adjoint operator (for some euclidean inner product space in $\mathbb{R}^3$)? If yes then find corresponding Gram matrix.

**My solution:** It is easy to compute that this matrix has $3$ eigenvalues, namely $\{-1,2,3\}$. We can find each corresponding eigenspace $V_{3}=\langle (1,0,0)\rangle,V_{2}=\langle (-1,1,0)\rangle, V_{-1}=\langle (3,-2,2)\rangle$. Hence this matrix is diagonalizable. And we have to find such inner product in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that those eigenvectors are orthogonal. More precisely, the function $$\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle:\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}, \quad \langle x,y\rangle=(x_1,x_2,x_3)A\begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2\\
y_3
\end{pmatrix}$$ where $A$ should be symmetric and positive definite, i.e. $A=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c\\
b & d & e\\
c & e & f
\end{pmatrix}$. Let''s denote vectors $(1,0,0), (-1,1,0), (3,-2,2)$ by $a_1,a_2,a_3$, respectively. Since we want $a_i\perp a_j$ for $i\neq j$.

Then condition $a_1\perp a_2$ implies that $b=a$. Condition $a_1\perp a_3$ implies $c=-\frac{a}{2}$. And condition $a_2\perp a_3$ implies that $e=d-\frac{3a}{2}$. So our matrix looks like $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a & a & -\frac{a}{2}\\
a & d & d-\frac{3a}{2}\\
-\frac{a}{2} & d-\frac{3a}{2} & f
\end{pmatrix}.$$ Since $A$ is positive definite then all upper-left submatrices should have positive determinants, i.e. it means that $$a>0, ad-a^2>0, \det A=\frac{a}{2}(d-a)(2f-2d+\frac{3a}{2})>0$$ which is equivalent to $$a>0, d>a,f>d-\frac{3a}{4}.$$

In particular If I take $a=2, d=4$ then $f>\frac{5}{2}$ and one can take $f=4$. So It means that Gram matrix can be taken as $$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2 & -1\\
2 & 4 & 1\\
-1 & 1 & 4
\end{pmatrix}$$ which makes our operator to be self-adjoint.

Comment: Are you asking us to verify your solution?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, yeah, please.  Is there some alternative way of the solution I'd be happy to take a look!

Comment: Once you have an eigenbasis for $A$, let $P$ be the matrix with those vectors as columns and set $G=P^{-T}P^{-1}$.

Comment: @amd, Could you explain in detail why such choice of $G=P^{-T}P^{-1}$ works, please?

Comment: @amd, what do you mean by $P^{-T}$?

Comment: $P^{-T}$ is a common notation for inverse transpose of $P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you’ve written, you’re looking for an inner product for which your eigenvectors are orthogonal. Strengthening this to having them be an orthonormal set, if $P$ is the matrix of eigenvectors, then this is equivalent to finding a symmetric matrix $G$ such that $P^TGP$ is diagonal, with positive diagonal entries. A simple choice for this diagonal matrix is the identity, and multiplying by inverses on both sides yields $G=P^{-T}P^{-1}$. Other choices for the diagonal matrix amount to scaling the eigenvectors.

For your choice of eigenvectors, this produces $$G=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&-\frac12\\1&2&\frac12\\-\frac12&\frac12&\frac32\end{bmatrix}.$$ For the $G$ that you came up with, we have $P^TGP=\operatorname{diag}(2,2,6)$.

Comment: Your $G$ should be positive definite matrix. Buy you did not mention it at all.

Comment: @ZFR That’s equivalent to the diagonal elements of $P^TGP$ being positive.

Comment: I am a bit confused to be honest. Whey are they equivalent?

Comment: I guess that I got your point. Let me write it in order to be sure that i am right.

Comment: Since the columns of $P$ are eigenvectors (I denoted them by $a_1,a_2,a_3$) and they form basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ then for any vector $x$ we have $x=\beta_1 a_1+\beta_2 a_2+\beta_3 a_3$ then $x^TGx=\sum _{i,j}\beta_i\beta_j a_i^TGa_j$ and since $P^TGP$ is diagonal then last sum is equal to $\sum \limits_{i=1}^3 \beta_i^2 \cdot [P^TGP]_{ii}>0$. Is this correct? Would be grateful if check this, please!

Comment: Could you answer to my question or not?

Comment: @ZFR You’re being awfully demanding and impatient for someone who’s asking favors of others.

Comment: But i really showed all my best. I am not asking for solution. I texted my approach and just asking for checking

Comment: @ZFR Anyway, I’d put it differently, but you’ve got the right idea. By construction, the quadratic form $\langle x,x\rangle$ reduces to a sum of terms of the form $\beta_i^2\langle a_i,a_i\rangle$, which is positive definite iff all of the $\langle a_i,a_i\rangle\gt0$, but these are precisely the diagonal elements of $P^TGP$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have noticed that in your reasoning you have never used that $G$ is symmetric, right? Symmetricity actually follows from $G=P^{-T}P^{-1}$.

Comment: @ZFR That’s right. It appears naturally in this derivation. Note also that only the symmetric part of a matrix $A$ contributes to the quadratic form $\mathbf x^TA\mathbf x$, so if we take the metric defined by that quadratic form instead of the inner product as the primitive, we can always symmetrize the matrix if necessary.